# React native google sign in along with firebase cloud message

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-ios, google-signin

For the react native ios app i enabled the Firebase cloud messaging. I downloaded the GoogleService-Info.plist and it works fine. When i tried to add the Google sign in from [here](https://github.com/react-native-google-signin/google-signin/blob/master/docs/get-config-file.md#without-firebase) . I tried to use the [instructions](https://github.com/react-native-google-signin/google-signin/blob/master/docs/get-config-file.md#without-firebase) but it seems that it tries to use the client id of the firebase instead the URLScheme. Is there any way to instruct which one it should use? I asked the same question [here](https://github.com/react-native-google-signin/google-signin/issues/974)

Comment: Can you post your code in your question?

Comment: What should i post? It is a configuration

Comment: why not follow "with firebase"? https://github.com/react-native-google-signin/google-signin/blob/master/docs/get-config-file.md#with-firebase

Comment: @user3009752 post the code you used to connect your app to firebase.  Redact the private info like keys of course...

Comment: @GazihanAlankus i followed the Without Firebase instructions. That's the problem. I setup the URLScheme as it says but it is not used

Comment: Can you paste your GoogleSignin.configure call?

Comment: Still looking for answers? @user3009752